# Delete when Table Rows are Swap

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table. When I swipe horizontally across a table cell a button appears asking if I want to delete the row.

I do not want that feature. However, I looked up the code up and down and I never see where does this feature is implemented.

Other rows on other tables do not behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
```

in your table's viewController.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I looked up the code up and down and I never see where does this feature is implemented.

It's implemented by the table view. You can prevent cells from being edited at all by returning NO from your table data source's implementation of `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`, and you can change what editing options are available for a given row by returning an appropriate value from `-tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Detemine if it's in editing mode
    if (self.editing) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```